# SimplePie RSS not accepting variable with comma separated strings

Tags: php, simplepie

I'm trying to use SimplePies `"$feed->set_feed_url (array());"` function but I am having major difficulty understanding why it wont accept my values.

When I add the URLS manually (i.e directly below), they work just fine. The feeds go through ok and displays the feeds as needed.

```
  $feed ->set_feed_url (array(
    'http://www.theverge.com/tag/rss',
    'http://feeds.ign.com/ign/all'
  ));
```

I have URLS in a database table that I am pulling out like normal with a while loop. I then append a comma and remove the trailing comma so its nice for the SimplePie array. Like so:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($pullAllAccountsDoIt)){
    $result4mdb .= $row[0] . ",";
}

$result4mdb = substr($result4mdb, 0, strlen($result4mdb) -1);
 echo "the result is: " . $result4mdb;
```

When I do this, and echo out "**$result4mdb**", it prints out: `the result is: http://www.gamespot.com/feeds/mashup/,http://www.theverge.com/tag/rss`

Meaning that the variable is good and printing out what i need. So far so good.
I then go into the simplePie code, put in my varialble like so:

```
$feed ->set_feed_url (array($result4mdb));
```

and nothing happens. I don't get any errors or anything, just that the page stays blank and nothing comes up.

For testing, I do a `gettype($result4mdb);` and it tells me that the variable is a "string" and again, the output of this variable when echoed is the URLS it got from the database so I KNOW that the whole process so far is working.

For further testing, I go to the database and remove one of the URLS so that when queried, that it returns one value, and all of the sudden SimplePie works.

I've been searching for a good day and a half now, trying different things and googling as much as possible but to no avail. I just cant quite get it.

I'm at my wits end. Any assistance as to why this isn't working is **GREATLY** appreciated.

Thank you in advance everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just producing a string containing comma seperated values. What you need is an array, so just `explode()` your string:

Change:

```
$feed ->set_feed_url (array($result4mdb));
```

to

```
$feed ->set_feed_url (explode(',', $result4mdb));
```

More elegant version, change:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($pullAllAccountsDoIt)){
    $result4mdb .= $row[0] . ",";
}
```

to

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($pullAllAccountsDoIt)){
    $result4mdb[] = $row[0];
}
```

This way you're not creating a string that needs to be exploeded, but create an array at first.

Comment: Ohhhhh i see what you did!!!!! clever! lol. Man i swear. My thinking was, since simplePie already said "array(my original var here)", then since my var already had the strings, it shoud've worked.  All i was trying to pass into the array was my string values. You just......I GET IT!!!  thank you man i appreciate it! It works!

Comment: Note: easier/more elegant way would be to modify your while loop to not create a string, but an array